# How to add a string to the "error array"?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am new to graphql.I use Node.js apollo-server.when I reset the error, the object is added to the error array.but how to do so to add a string and not an object ?.

**example**

```
throw Error("error")

{"errors":["error]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `formatError` from the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/).

> Functions to format the errors and response returned from the server, as well as the parameters to graphql execution(`runQuery`)

E.g.

`server.ts`

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    _: () => {
      throw new Error('error');
    },
  },
};
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  formatError(error: GraphQLError) {
    return error.message as any;
  },
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Apollo server is listening on ${url}`);
});
```

The GraphQL query for client-side:

```
query {
  _ 
}
```

The response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    "error"
  ],
  "data": {
    "_": null
  }
}
```